# Getting Twilio SMS Error For Free Trial Account

Tags: next.js, twilio, twiliosms

My message sending works fine in development environment for free trial but in production environment it gives error

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') I am using live credentials`

Any help??

I have added env variables of sid and auth token in production environment

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing the real code. However, I'd strongly advice against using a trial account for production env with any provider.